# Error with flutter_native_timezone while running Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-native-timezone

In my Flutter application, I have added this lib called `flutter_native_timezone` for the purpose of control date time of my notification service.

But seems that this environment is not working at all:

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' 
    // this version seems to not support flutter_native_timezone version 2.0.0 but idk if is that the main problem
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: app_name
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  firebase_core: ^2.5.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.3
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
  flutter_localizations: 
    sdk: flutter
    version: ^0.0.0
  intl: ^0.18.0

  timezone: ^0.9.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4
  // and many more, but not relevant
```

The error it returns on Debug Console is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_native_timezone' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

As it suggests, I tried to change Kotlin's version to 1.5.20 but it didn't worked.

Comment: some issue. i'm not sure, where 'flutter_native_timezone' come from and how i override it. and i'm not sure, why this old package is used. 2 years without update. do you have found a solution?

Comment: Actually no... haven't found a 'substitute' for the purpose of my project, so I got to remove the feature, but I'm still looking for the solution, maybe it's related to some incompatible version or so.

Comment: niw i found a solution for my case. i used 'device_calendar' package, which has used 'flutter_native_timezone'. So i found a workaround until the new version:    device_calendar: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/builttoroam/device_calendar.git
      ref: 4.3.1